# Where is one's "power"?

Tags: nietzsche, qualia

Where is one's "power", in the Nitezschean sense?

Is it in the body?

Is it a phenomena of conscious: does it depend upon consciousness?

Is it a quale?

It is essentially ones own?

Comment: sorry for the fairly dumb question, but it could have an interesting answer?

Comment: Don't talk yourself (or the question) down, I think the gist of the question is pretty good. Perhaps it would be benefitial to reword the question to ask either for the origin of and necessary faculties for power in the Nietzschean sense (freedom of will, genius; sources Nietzsche/secondary literature), or the ontological/ontic nature of it in modern terms (here, it could e.g. be asked whether it is purely qualitative and if this is compatible with determinism; sources ontological analyses of existentialism). As it stands, it seems to me that these two different aspects are a bit mingled.

Comment: In their genetics and history of their culture and immediate family?